# Why don't my code find a class upon rendering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have used jquery datatable. It has pagination buttons and upon rendering, I want to change its colours. I have noticed the class name which is **paginate_button current**. I have used .css function of jquery to change its css at loading but when I provide it like this

```
  $('.paginate_button, current').addClass('pagination-buttons');
```

it changes all navigation button's background colors.

and this fails to find a class

```
$('.paginate_button current').addClass('pagination-buttons');
```

Comment: try `$('.paginate_button.current').addClass('pagination-buttons');` You need to specify class with `.` selector

Answer (score 2):

If you want to target elements that have both `paginate_button` and `current` classes, do it with dot:

```
$('.paginate_button.current').addClass('pagination-buttons');
```

`.paginate_button, current` selects elements with class `paginate_button` and elements like `<current>`.

`.paginate_button current` selects elements like `<current>` nested under elements with class `paginate_button`.